# Vim not displaying deleted text correctly in tiling WM

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal, linux

I'm sorry if the question doesn't make much sense, but I really don't know how else to describe it. I'll do my best to clarify.

Let's say I have a text file containing the words

```
here is some text
```

If I were to place the cursor on the 'h' and press and hold <kbd>x</kbd> to delete the line (or any number of characters) it copies the last letter of the line over the rest of the text. If I were to delete the entire line by holding <kbd>x</kbd> it would then become

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but I can't move the cursor past the first column on that line, so the text is properly deleted, it just doesn't display correctly.

This also only happens in tiling window managers. I have tested it in ratpoison, StumpWM, spectrwm, dwm, and i3. I use XFCE4 as my everyday desktop and have been looking into switching to a tiling one, but without vim I can't do that. I have no idea why this is happening either, which makes it that much worse.

```
.vimrc:
set nocompatible
set number
syntax on
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2  
set incsearch
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
set ruler
set wildmenu  
set relativenumber
set showcmd
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set laststatus=2
set mat=2
set showmatch
set so=999
scriptencoding utf-8
set enc=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set matchpairs+=<:>
set matchpairs+=/:/
"Key Bindings
noremap <Up> <Nop>
noremap <Down> <Nop>
noremap <Left> <Nop>
noremap <Right> <Nop>
inoremap <Up> <Nop>
inoremap <Down> <Nop>
inoremap <Left> <Nop>
inoremap <Right> <Nop>
"vim-latexsuite mappings
filetype plugin on
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $* 
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
set iskeyword+=:
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you launch vim with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thanks, I'll just make an alias in my bashrc. Can you explain why it's doing this though?

Comment: Don't make an alias! That's a bad idea. The problem is something in your `.vimrc` and launching vim that way means "use no vimrc". Could you post your vimrc?

Comment: Done. Remember though, this only happens in tiling wms. It works fine in XFCE. Just added code formatting, forgot, sorry.

Comment: Does `:nmap x` reveal anything interesting?

Comment: I just tested this in i3, and I could not reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: Launched vim with no args, typed ':nmap x',  returned 'No mapping found'

Comment: Open one of the files that causes the odd behavior and do the same. It's very likely that it's one of the plugins you use.

Comment: It isn't a set of files, it's vim. Just did the same thing, vim, no args, still no mapping with spectrwm. vim -u NONE corrects the problem still.

Comment: After you see the x's does `:redraw!` fix it?

Comment: No, I've already tried that. Nor does C-L and C-R.

Comment: Cannot replicate on `xmonad`, but i'm commenting only to tell you that `set matchpairs+=/:/` does nothing.  You cannot have a `matchpairs` for the same character.

Comment: @grochmal, I'm pretty sure that was added by a LaTeX plugin I added. Thanks, I'll take it out.

Comment: You didn't mention the terminal you're using - try another (and gvim).

Comment: Well according to Archey, my shell is /bin/bash and my terminal is xterm. However, when I launch xterm via a command (Typing 'xterm' at the shell), the problem disappears. It seems that it is only happening from a shell created by the wm via the shortcut keys such as Meta-Enter in i3 or C-t x in ratpoison. What would the difference be between these two?

Comment: God, this really should be moved to the chat.  Did you configure your terminal in `i3`?  i.e. in `~/.config/i3/config` you should have something like: `bindsym $mod+Return exec xterm`.  The default `i3` terminal is rather wanky.  I have no clue about ratpoison, sorry.

Comment: Hear hear :) ^^^

Comment: is `:fixdel` helping ?

Comment: No, :fixdel didn't do anything.

Comment: @3p1k5auc3 I'm glad you fixed the problem! You should [self-answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing information into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out guys. I looked at the help entry for the '-u' command and saw there was also a '-u NORC' option which only skipped the vimrc file, not plugins. When I ran it, the problem was gone meaning that the problem had to be in the RC file. The first thing I did was delete the three lines regarding the enconding, but that didn't change anything either. After I looked at ':scriptnames' I saw there was another vimrc being loaded at /etc/vimrc, which was an exact copy of the one in my home directory prior to the edits I made. After commenting out the entire file and removing the comments one by one, I managed to figure out it is the

```
set enc=utf-8
```

line that was giving me all the trouble. My guess is that xterm was not being run in utf-8 mode, which was causing problems when trying to display (or more accurately delete) characters. Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: Yeah, xterm will not start in `utf-8` mode by default, for historical reasons.  Most distros will add `LANG=en_GB.utf-8` (or US, or whatever language you might be using) env variable to the x11 session but yours apparently is not doing it.  `.xinitrc` is a good place to force such definitions but not all display manger respect it.  There is a rather complete [answer on U&L about xterm encodings](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116404/how-to-make-the-login-shell-xterm-use-utf-8), it can guide you.

Comment: I doubt it, seeing as I'm using Arch. I'll definitely look over the guide, thanks!